# Pass logic function as parameter to general function

Tags: c#

Trying to reduse some code and follow the DRY principle with a generic approach. The code is kind of trivial, but I can not manage to compile it. I guess you see what I'm trying to do here (not repeat GetData(), but rather have several Logic() func's), what am I doing wrong?

**Caller:**

```
IEnumerable<IMyClass> result = Factory.GetData<IEnumerable<IMyClass>>("storedProsedureName", Factory.LogicFunction());
```

**Logic:**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string storedProsedureName, Func<string, OracleConnection, OracleCommand, IEnumerable<T>> functionCall) where T : class
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Helpers.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    return functionCall(storedProsedureName, conn, cmd);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }   

public static IEnumerable<IMyClass> LogicFunction(string storedProsedureName= "", OracleConnection conn = null, OracleCommand cmd = null)
{
    conn.Open();

    {...}

     conn.Close();
     return IEnumerable<IMyClass>;
}
```

**Error:**

> *Argument 2: cannot convert*
>
> from
>
> *'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable_IMyClass>'*
>
> to
>
> *'System.Func_string, OracleConnection, OracleCommand, IEnumerable _IEnumerable_IMyClass>>>'*

Comment: Omit the braces on `Factory.GetData<IEnumerable<IMyClass>>("storedProsedureName", Factory.LogicFunction);`.

Comment: In your Caller line, you are calling the ``LogicFunction``, and consequently passing the result of the call instead of the function itself; if you remove the ``()`` at the end, it should work.

Comment: @HimBromBeere thanks for pointing that out, you are of course right. Seems like a silly mistake from me.

Comment: @dumetrulo thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your caller to below code.

Removed `()` and also changed generic closing type from `IEnumerable<IMyClass>` to `IMyClass`.

```
IEnumerable<IMyClass> result = Factory.GetData<IMyClass>("storedProsedureName", Factory.LogicFunction);
```

Comment: This did indeed work, removing the `()` so I don't call the func but instead pass it and also change `GetData<IEnumerable<IMyClass>>` to `GetData<IMyClass>` did the trick. Tank you!